# Type casting of structures in C

Tags: c, casting, structure

I recently saw a code in C which had my wondering.

A simple form of the code is as below

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t easy;
    uint32_t hard;
}mode;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t status;
}type;

int main()
{
    type t2 = { 0 };
    type*   t1 = NULL;
    t1 = &t2;
    t1->status = 99;
    ((mode*)&(t1))->easy = 1;
    printf("%d", ((mode*)&(t1))->easy);
    scanf_s("%d", &((mode*)&(t1))->hard);
    printf("%d", ((mode*)&(t1))->hard);
    printf("%d", t1->status);
}
```

But when I execute the above, I get an error in the last printf statement as '**Access violation reading location 0x00000001**'.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nobody should ever program like this... don't even bother trying to figure it out.

Comment: Why are you surprised to get an access violation when referencing something like `((mode*)&(t1))->hard` clearly accessing memory outside the bounds of the type `type`?

Comment: This is casting of pointers to structure  (not structures, as the title suggests)

Comment: @FiddlingBits This was done by people in R&D, who were very conscious about each and every bit of the program. Thats why I posted this.

Comment: @lurker Error is not thrown on that line

Comment: @Vijayakumar Apparently they were not, since they have written fatal bugs. Bugs that was caused by their obscure programming style, which prevented them from understanding their own program.

Comment: @Vijayakumar when you get an access violation indicated on a given line of code it doesn't mean that's the line of code that caused the error. It might mean a prior line has an error, leading to the current line actually resulting in a fault due to corruption from the prior line or lines. That is likely what's happening here. What I indicated is an incorrect access to the `hard` member is definitely the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

This line stores an `int` in the space allocated for a pointer:

```
((mode*)&(t1))->easy = 1;
```

Since `t1` is a pointer, and your code takes a pointer to it with an ampersand, the value is not written to the `status` field of `t2`; it's written directly into the space of the pointer itself. This would correct the problem, writing `1` into the `status` field, which is also an alias for `easy`:

```
((mode*)t1)->easy = 1;
```

With this problem out of the way, the next problem happens on the `scanf_s` line. This line has undefined behavior, even if you remove the ampersand:

```
scanf_s("%d", &((mode*)&(t1))->hard); // <<== Undefined behavior
scanf_s("%d", &((mode*)(t1))->hard);  // <<== Also undefined behavior
```

The original line tries to write to stack memory past the place allocated to the `t1` pointer, causing stack corruption when returning from `scanf_s`.

The fixed line tries to write to the location of `hard` which is beyond the end of the `type` struct.

Note that it is OK to cast `type*` to `mode*` and access `easy` on it: when two `struct`s have identical initial members, you can freely cast pointers to one `struct` to pointer type of the other `struct`.

Comment: But _t1->status = 99;_ was also assigned and stored in memory. So, why is there an error thrown when I refer that member alone?

Comment: @Vijayakumar Oops, I missed the `&`. Your code is even more wrong than I though! Please see the edit.

Comment: The reason why accessing the `hard` member through a casted struct isn't safe is because there might (in theory) be padding bytes between `easy` and `hard`. In practice, it seems very unlikely that the compiler would insert any padding between two 32-bit integers and then it will work (even though it is still UB).

Comment: @Vijayakumar the code line that actually generates the access violation, and the code line that's at fault for this, can be two different lines. When memory becomes improperly accessed, it's ill effects aren't always immediately realized.

Answer (score 1):

At first everything looks fine. Even I was stuck at why is the throwing access violation. BTW the violation is at the last printf.

Then I realized the mistake. The t1 is already a pointer. They didn't have to do &(t1) everywhere. That changed the contents of t1 itself not the struct it was pointing to.
Secondly, there is not enough memory allocated to *t1 to be used as a mode
So you can make t2 to be of type mode and cast it before assigning it's address to t1. Else you end up editing the value to t1 when changing hard since t1 is just on the stack after t2

So the easy fix would be

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t easy;
    uint32_t hard;
}mode;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t status;
}type;

int main()
{
    mode t2 = { 0 };
    type*   t1 = NULL;
    t1 = (type*) &t2;
    t1->status = 99;
    ((mode*)(t1))->easy = 1;
    printf("%d", ((mode*)(t1))->easy);
    scanf_s("%d", &((mode*)(t1))->hard);
    printf("%d", ((mode*)(t1))->hard);
    printf("%d", t1->status);
}
```

And everything works as expected. No access violation.